# Contar cuantas veces aparece un valor en todo el dataframe - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un dataframe con la siguiente estructura,

```
User   t1   t1_p   t2   t2_p   t3   t3_p
U1     0    2      210  3      412  0
U2     0    3      322  4      496  4
U3     0    2      189  1      315  3
```

Las columnas con prefijo `_p` representan el nivel de precisión de los usuarios para cada tiempo. Tengo 5 niveles, de 0 a 4.

Mi pregunta es, ¿como puedo hacer un conteo de todo el dataframe (no por columnas) para saber cuantas veces hay cada nivel? Quiero saberlo de manera global, no por columnas o usuario.

Para el ejemplo quedaría,

- Nivel 0, 1.
- Nivel 1, 1.
- Nivel 2, 2.
- Nivel 3, 3.
- Nivel 4, 2.

He hecho lo siguiente,

```
suma= df.t1_p.value_counts() + df.t2_p.value_counts() + df.t3_p.value_counts() + df.t4_p.value_counts() + df.t5_p.value_counts() + df.p_th.value_counts()
```

El problema de esto es que si en alguna fila no aparece uno de los niveles, me pone un *NaN* ya que no lo traduce cómo un 0.

Para solucionar esto se me ha ocurrido añadir 5 filas extra con la función `pd.append()`, añadiendo así los 5 valores posibles pero... me parece un poco bastante feo.

¿Como podría hacerlo de una manera más limpia este conteo?

**Edit**

Pensé que los *NaN* venían por ser string los valores de esa columna, pero aún pasándolos a entero siguen saliendo.

```
df[["t1_p", "t2_p", "t3_p"]] = df[["t1_p", "t2_p", "t3_p"]].astype(int)
```

¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para reproducir el problema:

```
import io
import pandas as pd


data = io.StringIO("""\
User   t1   t1_p   t2   t2_p   t3   t3_p
U1     0    2      210  3      412  0
U2     0    3      322  4      496  4
U3     0    2      189  1      315  3
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\s+",  engine="python")
```

Si quieres ver las veces que cada valor aparece en las `n` columnas en conjunto, usando `pandas.Series.value_counts` puedes concatenar las Series en un `DataFrame` y aplicar `sum` sobre las filas:

```
suma= pd.concat(
    [df.t1_p.value_counts(), df.t2_p.value_counts(), df.t3_p.value_counts()], 
    axis=1
    ).sum(axis=1)
```

> ```
> >>> suma
>
> 0    1.0
> 1    1.0
> 2    2.0
> 3    3.0
> 4    2.0
> ```

## Usando `numpy.unique`

```
import numpy as np

index, counts = np.unique(
    df[["t1_p", "t2_p", "t3_p"]].to_numpy(),
    return_counts=True
    )
suma = pd.Series(counts,  index)
```

> ```
> >>> suma
>
> 0    1
> 1    1
> 2    2
> 3    3
> 4    2
> ```